# Unable to resolve symbol: is in this context

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, test-is

I'm brand new to Clojure, and I am having a bit of trouble getting unit tests running.

```
(ns com.bluepojo.scratch
  (:require clojure.test))

(defn add-one
  ([x] (+ x 1))
  )

(is (= (add-one 3) 4))
```

gives:

```
java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: is in this context
```

What am I missing?

Update:

This works:

```
(clojure.test/is (= (add-one 3) 4))
```

How do I make it so that I don't have to declare clojure.test before the is?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your use of the ns macro is not quite correct and you have several options to fix it. I would suggest one of

## 1. Alias `clojure.test` to something shorter

```
(ns com.bluepojo.scratch
  (:require [clojure.test :as test))

(defn add-one
  ([x] (+ x 1)))

(test/is (= (add-one 3) 4))
```

## 2. Use `use`

```
(ns com.bluepojo.scratch
  (:use [clojure.test :only [is]]))

(defn add-one
  ([x] (+ x 1)))

(is (= (add-one 3) 4))
```

Take a look at [this article](http://blog.8thlight.com/articles/2010/12/6/clojure-libs-and-namespaces-require-use-import-and-ns) which explains this at some length

Comment: You're missing a closing `]` in the `:require` sexp and `use` is deprecated now in favor of `require` with `:refer`.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `require` and **`refer`**

```
(ns com.bluepojo.scratch
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all))
```

Then simply

```
(is (= (add-one 3) 4))
(are ...)
```

`:refer` also takes a list of symbols to refer from the namespace (e.g. `:refer [is are]`).