# How to use clojure.test methods from repl?

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

I tried the methods specified in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457321/unable-to-resolve-symbol-is-in-this-context) post, but it shows that `is` cannot be resolved to a symbol. How to use the clojure.test methods for unit testing?

```
user=> (ns clojure.test)
nil
clojure.test=> (is (= 4 4))
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: is in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:55:1)
clojure.test=> (is (= 4 4))
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: is in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:56:1)
clojure.test=> (:require [clojure.test :as test])
CompilerException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: clojure.test, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:57:1)
clojure.test=> (ns user)
nil
user=> (:require [clojure.test :as test])
CompilerException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: clojure.test, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:59:1)
user=> (ns a (:require [clojure.test :as test]))
nil
a=> (test/is (= 1 1))
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such var: test/is, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:61:1)
a=> (ns a (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]))
nil
a=> (is (= 2 2))
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: is in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:63:1)
a=>
```

Comment: Can you please show us your code? (`ns` / `require` block and the line with `is`)?

Comment: probably you aren't in `clojure.test` scope. `refer` to it by (clojure.core/refer 'clojure.test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
(ns my-project.my-ns-test
  (:require [my-ns :as sut]
            [clojure.test :refer :all]))

(deftest my-ns-fn-test    (testing "can add"
    (is (= 3 (sut/add 1 2)))))


(comment  ;; ie. in your REPL  
          ;;https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.test/run-tests 
  (run-tests 'my-project.my-ns) ;; {:test 1, :pass 1, :fail 0, :error 0, :type :summary}
  )
```

Also see: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.test/run-all-tests

Answer (score 2):

This is my favorite way. Files look like this:

```
~/clj > ls -ldF **/core.*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alan alan  40 Oct  7 15:32 src/clj/core.clj
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alan alan 618 Oct  7 15:34 test/tst/clj/core.clj
```

Main code:

```
(ns clj.core)

(defn add [x y] (+ x y))
```

Test code:

```
(ns tst.clj.core
  (:use clj.core
        clojure.test ))

(deftest t-op
  (is (= 3 (add 1 2)))
)
```

First, check the test is actually being run. Change the correct value `3` to a dummy value like `99`:

```
(deftest t-op
  (is (= 99 (add 1 2)))
)
```

Run the tests from the command line and see it fail:

```
 > lein test

lein test tst.clj.core

lein test :only tst.clj.core/t-op

FAIL in (t-op) (core.clj:25)
expected: (= 99 (add 1 2))
  actual: (not (= 99 3))

Ran 1 tests containing 1 assertions.
1 failures, 0 errors.
Tests failed.
```

Then, put back the actual test value, re-run, and see it pass:

```
> lein test
lein test tst.clj.core

Ran 1 tests containing 1 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```